# How do I word wrap the text of an <a> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have an  tag in a document, and the display text is a fairly long email address. On smaller displays (like a phone) the email address hangs outside the container it's in. How can I make it wrap? I've probably got the container itself setup wrong, but can't figure out what to change. Here is my code for that particular area:

```css
#facebook {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 55%;
  border: 10px solid darkred;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 23%;
  top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.word-break {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div id="facebook">
  <h1>Contact Blackbird Music</h1>
  <br>
  <h2>Email: <a class="word-break" href="mailto:blackbirdmusicacademy@gmail.com">blackbirdmusicacademy@gmail.com</a></h2>
  <h2>Phone: <a href="tel:+17703175855">(770) 317-5855</a></h2>
  <h2>Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text</h2>
  <h2>Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text</h2>
  <h2>Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text</h2>
  <h2>Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text</h2>
</div>
```

I've tried the word-wrap inside the #facebook ID, and I've also tried putting the text of the email address inside a separate div with its own class or ID. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks normal to me, even in small screens: https://jsfiddle.net/1jrwfd4n/

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you can swap out `word-break: break-all;` with `overflow-wrap: break-word;`. That should do it :)

Source: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use word-wrap as below

```css
#facebook {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 55%;
  border: 10px solid darkred;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 23%;
  top: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.word-break {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="facebook">
  <h1>Contact Blackbird Music</h1>
  <br>
  <h2>Email: <a class="word-break" href="mailto:blackbirdmusicacademy@gmail.com">blackbirdmusicacademy@gmail.com</a></h2>
  <h2>Phone: <a href="tel:+17703175855">(770) 317-5855</a></h2>
  <h2>Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text</h2>
  <h2>Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text</h2>
  <h2>Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text</h2>
  <h2>Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text Filler Text</h2>
</div>
```